# Overleaf compiler failes, package** ifthen** is probably missing

Tags: packages, compiling, overleaf

I am new to LaTex and having troubles to compile a template on Overleaf.

There is a package called **ifthen** and it seems like it is not pre-installed on Overleaf. I include **\usepackage{ifthen}** but there is an error of **Undefined control sequence** as in the attached photo.[image].

How should I solve this problem? I think I should add this package to Overleaf but I do not know how to do that. I checked https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen?lang=en and downloaded the .zip file from there, but do not know how to procedd any further.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: no the error is that `\zweiseitig` is not defined, replace that by `twoside`.

Comment: do not show code as an image, but the error does not say `ifthen` is not installed, it is the undefined command in your `\documentclass` option

Comment: It should be noted that the error message is not particularly helpful here, as it seems to suggest that `ifthen` is the problem which is not true. Note that the second error is related to the command `\biber` not being defined, you should fix that as well. It looks like you had a list of settings at some point (either on top of the current file or in a different file that was loaded at the start of the current file) that is now missing.

Comment: What happens in lines 1--26 or your tex file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \zweiseitig

l.34 \usepackage
               {ifthen}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

and the control sequence at the end of the top line is `\zweiseitig`.

When LaTeX processes `\documentclass`, it goes beyond `{article}` to see whether `[` follows. Since it doesn't find it, it start processing the options to `\documentclass` and stops with an error because of the undefined control sequence. Since TeX has already read `\usepackage`, it shows the point at which it currently is, because it has no ways to determine where *precisely* `\zweiseitig` was.

My hunch is that you (or someone else who passed you the preamble) used to process the document `ba.tex` from the command line with something like

```
pdflatex "\def\zweiseitig{twoside}\input{ba}"
```

or

```
pdflatex "\def\zweiseitig{oneside}\input{ba}"
```

but this is not possible with Overleaf (or, maybe, you can with a suitable `latexmkrc` file).